# Postscript file syntax query

Tags: postscript

I have a couple of postscript that essentially represents same graphical information albeit differently.

I do not understand the syntax and hence would appreciate if someone help understand the difference between the following (sample) lines -

Lines from File 1 -

```
0 0 0 1 scol  L N 232 3740 M 232 3475 I 232 3475 I 233 3475 I 233 3475 I 233 3740 I 233 3740 I 232 3740 I 232 3740 I C 

233 3475 M 550 3475 I 551 3475 I 551 3475 I 550 3475 I 233 3475 I 232 3475 I 232 3475 I 233 3475 I C 

233 3739 M 550 3739 I 551 3739 I 551 3740 I 550 3740 I 233 3740 I 232 3740 I 232 3739 I 233 3739 I C
```

Lines from file 2 -

```
0 0 0 1 scol  L N 232 3740 M 232 3475 I 232 3474 I 233 3474 I 233 3475 I 233 3740 I 233 3740 I 232 3740 I 232 3740 I C 

 L N 233 3474 M 550 3474 I 551 3474 I 551 3476 I 550 3476 I 233 3476 I 232 3476 I 232 3474 I 233 3474 I C 

 L N 233 3739 M 550 3739 I 551 3739 I 551 3740 I 550 3740 I 233 3740 I 232 3740 I 232 3739 I 233 3739 I C
```

I am guessing one of them is drawing line(s) and another drawing rectangle. Could be complete wrong...

Any help would be really appreciated.

Also, any reference links to postscript language syntax would help too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

postscript is a programing language. `scol,L,N,M,I,C, etc` are functions that presumably have been defined elsewhere.

Look earlier in the code and you should proably find things like

```
/M {moveto} def
/N {newpath} def
```

then start reading the manual to sort it out..

www.adobe.com/products/postscript/pdfs/PLRM.pdf

btw I'd guess your guess is correct.:

```
newpath x0 y0 moveto x1 y1 lineto x2 y2 lineto ... xn yn lineto stroke
```

is a pretty typical construct to draw a line

Comment: +1 Agree. And `scol` is probably `{setcolor}` with a cmyk colorspace.